# Email error: Message is not sending to the email instead it is printing in the terminal

Tags: python, django, email-validation, django-email, django-messages

When I am registering as a new user or want to change my password, then the Message which is needed to be sent to the email is showing in the terminal instead. Here is the terminal picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ss7U.png)

Here is the views.py function.

```
from aiohttp import request
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from companies.models import Company
from accounts.roles import UserRole
# User mode
from .models import CustomUser
from domains.models import Domain
from dashboard.models import MarketingHome, SliderHome
# Custom forms
from .forms import PublicCustomUserChangeForm, CustomChangePasswordForm
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from allauth.account.views import SignupView, LoginView



@login_required
def change_password_user(request):
    company = CustomUser.get_company(request.user)

    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CustomChangePasswordForm(request.user)
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'company': company
        }
        return render(request, 'account/change_password_user.html', context)
    else:
        form = CustomChangePasswordForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('account_change_password_user')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
            return redirect('account_change_password_user')
```

here is the registration function:

```
class AccountSignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = "account/signup.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        current_site = self.request.META['HTTP_HOST']
        context = super(SignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {
            'slider': SliderHome.objects.filter(domain_site__domain__contains=current_site, is_active=True),
            # 'current_domain': Domain.objects.filter(site__domain__contains=current_site).first()
        }
        return context


account_signup_view = AccountSignupView.as_view()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using `EMAIL_BACKEND` in `settings.py` as this way:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Instead change it to your desired email backend.

Example -

`'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'`
`'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`

Comment: Thank you for your help. it changes something but now I am getting a different error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: i solve errors and change the settings and now it is showing this error and i have tried the correct password and also the app password we get at google 2 step verification.

(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError q7-20020a170902dac700b0018544ad1e8esm7921505plx.238 - gsmtp', 'greatkart24@gmail.com')